# closing PDO connections issue

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

i have a problem with PDO connection !
i read that i don't wanted to close PDO connection beacause will auto closed !
but if u want to close it manually i need to assign Null to connection variable .
but i use a data base class and the DB query run like this !

```
$addUser = users::getInstance()->userAdd($data);
```

and users class contain the following

```
class users extends DB {
private static $_instance = null;   
public static function getInstance(){

if (!isset(self::$_instance)){
    self::$_instance = new users();
}
return self::$_instance;
} 
 [...]
 }
```

and Data base class

```
    class DB {

    private static $_instance = null;
    private $_con;
        [...]

    public function __construct(){
        try{
    $this->_con = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost';dbname=db,user,pass);  
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            die ($e->getMessage());
        }
    } 

public function __destruct (){
    $this->close();
}

public static function getInstance(){
    if (!isset(self::$_instance)){
        self::$_instance = new DB();
    }
    return self::$_instance;
}

public function close(){
    $this->_con = null;
}
[...] }
```

the problem is that the script don't close the connections because when i limit max users connections in my localhost or use a free webhost service that already limit it i get this error message

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1203] User 'userName' already has more than 'max_user_connections' active connections
```

i need a solution to avoid this error message by closing connection while i using  instance method in order to establish a connection !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Get rid of DB class.
2. Do not extend application class from DB class.
3. Do not play with static magic.
4. Create raw PDO object and pass it in application class
5. Forget about this connection stuff

So it goes:

```
$pdo  = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db','user','pass');    
$user = new users($pdo);
$user->select();

class users
{
    protected $db;

    function __construct($pdo){
        $this->db = $pdo;
    }
    function select()
    {
        $this->db->query("select 1");
    }
}
```

this way only **one** connection per script instance will be created and you will never face such an error again.

Comment: How to use it then, if I wanted to pass `$pdo` to the constructor of a particular class and share it there without using `global`? When using DI container it returns an error.

Comment: Just  pass $pdo to the constructor and assign it to a local variable

Comment: Come on. Passing $pdo to the constructor and assign it to a local variable IS a DI. How come it doesn't work?

Comment: This is what I was asking myself. I get strange warning `Warning: Missing argument 2 for Database::__construct()` and then `Notice: Undefined variable: pdo in`. If I do the same but use `global $pdo` in the constructor - then it works. Why this could be happening? I'm using *Dice DIC* (http://r.je/dice.html), by the way.

Comment: Alright, I think I just noticed that upon instantiation you add `new users($pdo);` I think I should setup rules for the container to use.

Comment: Just to reduce confusion: DIC is not DI. Yes, you have to set up rules for DIC

Answer (score 0):

I am leaving this here as a reminder to me to think first before posting 'less than useful' answers. ;-/

Please use the answer provide by  'Your common sense' with the **global, re-used connection**.

do not read any further...

Stop throwing the unused connections away! Leave them active!

When you have finished with the 'connection' return it to a 'free list' array. do not destroy it

1) When you want a new database connection then check the 'free list'. Grab the top free one if available.

2) if no free ones available, create one and use it.

3) put it into the free list when you finish with it. Do not close it!

Implement the 'free list' as a 'stack'. I also kept a 'list of active connections'. when one completes just return it to the 'free list'.

This works a lot

You may run out of 'database handles' but you would need ten active overlapping active transactions.

Comment: there is no such thing like "free list" in PHP

Comment: @Your Common Sense, Ok, i agree, i should have coded it explicitly as a class that looks after open connections with the required array. was lazy on my part.

Comment: Look, you are taking PHP essentially wrong. There is not, and shouldn't be anything like list of connections, be it "free list" or "required array". PHP script runs lice a cli program - strats, runs and dies. There is no environment to hold a connection pool for it - neither inside or outside. Every PHP instance can only open a brand new connection, directly to the DB, without any lists.

Comment: and PHP script instance itself should not hold a pool of connections either. it's execution is linear, so there is no use to have more than single connection. and for the performance sake there should be always one single connection

Comment: disclaimer for the context-unaware nitpickers: I am well aware of the persistent connections and of multiple connections with different credentials - probably, more aware than you. It is not the case here.

Comment: @Your Common Sense, yes! i appreciate your comments and agree with them. I do understand about PHP. i really do understand about database connections. I thought i had made it clear in my answer that i agreed completely with your approach and not to even consider mine.